# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin error

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
class DbConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        //Registering the driver
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

        //establish the connection with database
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@194.16.247.96:1521:onlspn","onlinedbs", "onlinedbs");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select serno,amt_card from AUTHORIZATIONS where " 
                + " SERNO > ( select max(SERNO)-200 from AUTHORIZATIONS ) and source "
                + "in ('VISA','MA01','MA02','MA03','MA10','MA11','MA12','AMA1','AMA2','AMP1','AMP2') order by serno desc");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int empid = rs.getInt("serno");
            String fname = rs.getString("amt_card");

            System.out.println(empid +'\t'+ fname);
    }
    }

}
```

Guys help me connect to my remote Database

Comment: What JDBC jar file is on your classpath?

Comment: ojdbc6.jar. As I am working with eclipse I have added jar there also

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`, so it correctly identified `jdbc:oracle:thin` as a JDBC URL for the Oracle driver to handle.

Comment: FYI: The `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the `ojdbc6.jar` file I'm using says `Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.3.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried out your code with ojdbc6.jar on the classpath, it compiles and runs fine.
However, when you run your code, it can't find a suitable driver. That can mean two things:

1. (invalid option as pointed out by Andreas - the new OracleDriver() would fail) The driver isn't on the runtime classpath. Double check that it's included in the classpath when you run your program.
2. (invalid option since the code runs fine in my test) There's a syntax error in your JDBC URL.
3. You're using an old version of the Oracle JDBC driver. Download the latest ojdbc6.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: Can't be #1 or the `new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()` would fail.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't hit the line where it complains about jdbc:oracle:thin. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still I didn't get what to do.  Tell me clearly what should I check now?

Comment: Option 3: download the latest ojdbc6.jar.